# Last element of list not displayed. \tl_use not executed?

Tags: amsmath, xparse

I am trying to set up a macro formatting a particular type of mathematical quantity appropriately. The quantity T does take two sets of arguments to be displayed in a smallmatrix.

It works almost as expected. The last element of each set however is **not** displayed. If I remove the "&" (in the line starting with \seq_map_inline) everything is fine but then the colums aren't aligned properly.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\DeclareMathOperator{\TL}{T}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Tgennew}{m m}
{\TL\left[\begin{smallmatrix} \Tgennew_print:n {#1} \\ \Tgennew_print:n {#2} \end{smallmatrix}\right]
}

\seq_new:N \l_Tgennew_list_seq
\tl_new:N \l_Tgennew_last_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \Tgennew_print:n #1
{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_Tgennew_list_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_Tgennew_list_seq \l_Tgennew_last_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_Tgennew_list_seq { ##1 , &  }
  \tl_use:N \l_Tgennew_last_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
$\Tgennew{111,2,3333,4,5}{a,b,c,d,eee}$

or, with a couple of variables:

$\Tgennew{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_\ell}{\beta_1, \beta_2, \dots, \beta_\ell}$
\end{document}
```

How can I display the two sets of arguments completely and properly aligned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the token list variable is set in a cell of the small matrix and you try to use it in another one.

You might pop the first item, instead, but there's a better way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\DeclareMathOperator{\TL}{T}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Tgennew}{m m}
 {
  \TL\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
  \Tgennew_print:n {#1} \\
  \Tgennew_print:n {#2}
  \end{smallmatrix}\right]
 }

\seq_new:N \l_Tgennew_list_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \Tgennew_print:n #1
{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_Tgennew_list_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_Tgennew_list_seq { , & }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
$\Tgennew{111,2,3333,4,5}{a,b,c,d,eee}$

or, with a couple of variables:

$\Tgennew{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_\ell}{\beta_1, \beta_2, \dots, \beta_\ell}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

A variant that allows more than two rows (or even just one)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\DeclareMathOperator{\TL}{T}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Tgennew}{m}
 {
  \TL\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
  \Tgennew_make:n { #1 }
  \end{smallmatrix}\right]
 }

\seq_new:N \l_Tgennew_rows_seq
\seq_new:N \l_Tgennew_list_seq
\tl_new:N \l_Tgennew_body_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \Tgennew_make:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_Tgennew_rows_seq { ; } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_Tgennew_rows_seq
   {
    \Tgennew_makerow:n { ##1 }
   }
  \tl_use:N \l_Tgennew_body_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \Tgennew_makerow:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_Tgennew_list_seq { , } { #1 }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l_Tgennew_body_tl
   {
    \seq_use:Nn \l_Tgennew_list_seq { , & }
    \exp_not:N \\
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
$\Tgennew{111,2,3333,4,5;a,b,c,d,eee}$

\bigskip

$\Tgennew{
  \alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_\ell;
  \beta_1, \beta_2, \dots, \beta_\ell;
  \gamma_1, \gamma_2, \dots, \gamma_\ell
}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution. I still have trouble understanding why my approach did not work properly - I would appreciate if you could point this out more clearly and elaborate. Why is the token list variable set in one cell of the small matrix and I am trying to use it in another? Where do I switch the cell? I tried to understand via source3.pdf, but some additional information would still be of help.

Comment: @jbroedel The sequence and the token list are set when TeX has already started the alignment; then `\seq_map_inline:Nn` delivers the whole result. As soon as the first `&` is processed, the implicit group for the first cell ends, so both the sequence and the token list are restored their previous value.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, one could use a TABstack.  Here, I specify a space as the column separator (rather than the default `&`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\DeclareMathOperator{\TL}{T}

\setstackTAB{ } % COLUMN SEPARATOR
\TABstackMath % STACK MATH BY DEFAULT
\def\stackalignment{r} % RIGHT ALIGN COLUMNS
\TABstackMathstyle{\scriptstyle} % FORMAT OF CELL ENTRIES
\setstacktabbedgap{3pt} % INTER-COLUMN GAP
\def\stacktype{S} % STACK WITH FIXED GAP BETWEEN ROWS
\setstackgap{S}{1pt} % GAP BETWEEN ROWS
\begin{document}
$\TL\Bigl[\tabbedstackanchor{111, 2, 3333, 4, 5}{a, b, c, d, eee}\Bigr]$

$\TL\bigl[\tabbedstackanchor{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_\ell}
  {\beta_1, \beta_2, \dots, \beta_\ell}\bigr]$
\end{document}
```

[image]